# Java PrintWriter increase buffer size

Tags: java, buffer, printwriter

I wrote this program to create really long lists of test numbers of about 10^9 characters per file. The printing process is slowing me down. I am using PrintWriter and writing to a file. I can allocate a lot more memory to the PrintWriter buffer, but I don't think there is a way.

TL; DR: How do I increase PrintWriter's buffer size?

Comment: Wrap the writer in a `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: did not know about that. why don't they just give printwriter a buffer size constructor argument as well? pritnwriter has more utility than bufferedwriter anyways

Comment: Because `PrintWriter` doesn't have a buffer.

Answer (score 1):

[`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) doesn't have a buffer.

Technically, `PrintWriter` should have only one constructor:

```java
PrintWriter(Writer out, boolean autoFlush)
```

All the [other constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#constructor.summary) are there as a *convenience* for your use. If you need something more than what they provide, such as control over the buffer size of the `BufferedWriter` created by some of those constructors, you have to do it yourself.

As an example, the following two statements do the same:

```java
OutputStream out = ...;

new PrintWriter(out, true) // convenience

new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out)), true)
```

So, if you want to control the buffer size, you can't use the *convenience* constructor, but have to do it the long way, so you can add the buffer size to the `BufferedWriter` constructor:

```java
int bufferSize = 16384;

new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out), bufferSize), true)
```